# Making a Clothing GUI 2021 (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I Am Trying to make a GUI that gives you an outfit when you Click it (Text Button). Its Currently not Working. This is the Script I used.

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:FindFirstChild(function(WhoClick)

    local WhoClick = game.Players.LocalPlayer

    local Shirt = ""-------Shirt Link Goes here
    local Pants = ""-------Pants Link Goes Here

    local PlayerShirt = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(WhoCLick.Name).Shirt
    local PlayerPants = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(WhoCLick.Name).Pants

    PlayerShirt.ShirtTemplate = Shirt
    PlayerPants.PantsTemplate = Pants
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

`.FindFirstChild(function())` won't work.
Instead, do this (I used random templates for examples purposes):

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(WhoClick)
    WhoClick.Character.Shirt.ShirtTemplate = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=57282083"
    WhoClick.Character.Clothing.Template = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id= 6714633844"
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got that code from but it cannot work.

You want to implement an event listener for the gui buttons MouseButton1Click event.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/GuiButton/MouseButton1Click

Instead you try to call [Instance:FindFirstChild](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/FindFirstChild) with it.

Please refer to the Roblox manual.

Implement the listener as a function and call the buttons Connect function like in the following example. This will register your event listener to the click event.

> ```
> function leftClick()
>   print("Left mouse click")
> end
>  
> script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(leftClick)
> ```

Alternatively this will also work:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function () 
      print("Left mouse click")
    end)
```